# Rvest: navigating html nodes

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am attempting to scrape results data from [HLTV.org](https://www.hltv.org/results):  I'm aiming to scrape the winner, loser and date of each match.

I have successfully scraped the winner & loser of each match- the structure of the date is where I'm struggling.
The results for each day are held within `<div class="results-sublist">`
The value for the date is held in a span nested within that div (NB: Chrome tells me that it's a div, which is a lie):

```
 <div class="standard-headline">Results for December 28th 2020</div>
```

On the same 'level' as this span (i.e. directly below the "results-sublist" div, we have the results for each match played on that day.

Before looping through each day, I am attempting to create a table with the results from one day.

My current code is as follows:

```
url <- "https://www.hltv.org/results"
s <- rvest::html_session(url)
s_tree <- xml2::read_html(s)


day_results_nodes <- s_tree %>%
 html_nodes(xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'results-sublist')]")

i <- day_results_nodes[[1]]

date <- i %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//span[contains(@class, 'standard-headline')]") %>%
  html_text()

winner <- i %>%
 xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@class, 'team team-won')]") %>%
 rvest::html_text()

loser <- i %>%
 xml2::xml_find_all(xpath="//div[@class='team ']") %>%
 rvest::html_text()

page_results <- cbind(winner, loser, x1 = date)
```

page_results (actually returned)

|  | winner | loser | x1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ex-ETHEREAL | Lyngby Vikings | Results for December 28th 2020 |
| 2 | Winstrike | MBAPPEEK | Results for December 27th 2020 |
| 3 | Project X | Lilmix | Results for December 25th 2020 |
| 4 | Budapest Five | Lilmix | Results for December 24th 2020 |
| 5 | Project X | The Incas | Results for December 23rd 2020 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 100 | Movistar Riders | Endpoint | Results for December 28th 2020 |

page_results (expected)

|  | winner | loser | x1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ex-ETHEREAL | Lyngby Vikings | Results for December 28th 2020 |
| 2 | Winstrike | MBAPPEEK | Results for December 28th 2020 |
| 3 | Project X | Lilmix | Results for December 28th 2020 |

Positives:
The day_results_nodes behaves as anticipated. day_results_nodes returns 11 html nodes, each of which has as many divs below it as there were matches on the day.

Negatives:
page_results returns a table of the 100 results on the webpage rather than the four matches attached to the first "results-sublist" div.
the dates column simply cycles through the 11 available dates on the webpage, rather than the date corresponding to the 'standard headline' corresponding to each match (I was expecting to broadcast the single date value over each row within the day's 'results-sublist')

I get the following warning message:

> Warning in cbind(winner, loser, x1 = date) :   number of rows of
> result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 3)

I presume that this is a byproduct of the broadcast not working as anticipated.

I am unclear as to why `i <- day_results_nodes[[1]]` does not appear to reference the first node (i.e. data for results from the most recent day); printing i returns an html node with a span and three classes as expected.
This leads me to believe that my error lies in the xml_find_all(), though I do not understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xml_find_all` was starting from root node as you didn't add the leading `.` to your xpath. I show corrected at end.

From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xml2/versions/1.3.2/topics/xml_find_all):

[image]

You want the right number of nodes in each group (e.g. 1 date versus same number of winner as losers) so that date recycling correctly populates. Each block should return a single date so you only need `html_node`; for the winners/losers I would switch to css as this returns the right number of nodes relative to the current node (from your index).  It is also faster to use css. To get the right number of losers I use `:not` pseudo class selector to remove the nodes with multi-valued classes for winners; which had the `team-won` class.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://www.hltv.org/results"
s <- rvest::html_session(url)
s_tree <- xml2::read_html(s)

day_results_nodes <- s_tree %>%
  html_nodes('.results-sublist')

i <- day_results_nodes[[1]]

date <- i %>%
  html_node('.standard-headline') %>%
  html_text()

winner <- i %>%
  html_nodes('.team-won') %>%
  html_text()
   
loser <- i %>%
  html_nodes('.team:not(.team-won)') %>%
  html_text()

page_results <- cbind(winner, loser, x1 = date)
```

---

xpath

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://www.hltv.org/results"
s <- rvest::html_session(url)
s_tree <- xml2::read_html(s)


day_results_nodes <- s_tree %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'results-sublist')]")

i <- day_results_nodes[[1]]

date <- i %>%
  html_node(xpath = ".//span[contains(@class, 'standard-headline')]") %>%
  html_text()

winner <- i %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all(".//div[contains(@class, 'team team-won')]") %>%
  rvest::html_text()

loser <- i %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all(xpath=".//div[@class='team ']") %>%
  rvest::html_text()

page_results <- cbind(winner, loser, x1 = date)

page_results
```